# D8 Commerce - Non-orderable product

Tags: commerce

What's the best way to configure some products so that they are not on sale .. i.e not show the price or add to cart button without creating a new product type?

Comment: ok there are a few ways to go about this ... but not defaut functionality as products assume you want to sell stuff ... have you thought of creating a config entity  where you could mark products that are not for sale ?

Comment: wait i used to work for you guys ... give me a call lol.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas...

1) create custom config entity like "products_not_on_sale"

2) Alter node view to hide the fields if referenced in above ^

--- or ---

1) add new field of type bool to say item on sale or not.

2) alter node view to hide fields if value is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to uncheck the `active` option on each product variation. That will hide the "Add to cart" button and price without hidding the product or its information.

[image]

Comment: Thanks .. I also needed to hide the price. Checking that option still displays the price.

Comment: I've tried this on a live site an also on simplytest.me with a clean commerce site. It hides price and "add to cart" button. At least in the product page.

Comment: I'm using Panelizer and I don't think it works with that module. I turned Panelizer off for the product page and the Active switch appears to wiork

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I ended up achieving what I wanted in a twig template by copying it from the below path:

```
modules/contrib/commerce/modules/product/templates/commerce-product-variation.html.twig
```

to:

```
themes/custom/mytheme/templates/product/commerce-product-variation--summary.html.twig
```

"summary" is the display for the panels page I've configured.

Then used the variation active status boolean value to determine whether or not to show it:

```
{% if product_variation_entity.status.value != 0 %}
<div{{ attributes }}>
  {{- product_variation -}}
</div>
{% endif %}
```